Boundary terms of integration by part depends on the order to exchange the differetial operator
I have a very simple question while learning calculus. Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth domain. $f,g\in C^\infty(\Omega)$. We consider the integration by part here:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega}(\partial_1\partial_2f)g&=-\int_{\Omega}(\partial_1f)(\partial_2g)+\int_{\partial\Omega}(\partial_1 f) g\nu_2\\
&=\int_{\Omega}f(\partial_1\partial_2g)-\int_{\partial\Omega}f (\partial_2 g)\nu_1+\int_{\partial\Omega}(\partial_1 f) g\nu_2
\end{aligned}
$$
However, if we first exchange $\partial_1$ then $\partial_2$, we will have:
$$
\int_{\Omega}(\partial_1\partial_2f)g=\int_{\Omega}f(\partial_1\partial_2g)-\int_{\partial\Omega}f (\partial_1 g)\nu_2+\int_{\partial\Omega}(\partial_2 f) g\nu_1$$
The boundary parts here depends on the order of exchanging the differential operators. Do we have any formula for it?
